# A Day in a Life o' Me

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *I form ticks and crosses, 
>  But I have not a pen. 
>  You check me during pauses, 
>  Every now and then. 
>  
>  I have a pair of hands, 
>  But I have not an arm. 
>  Every day demands, 
>  For me to use my charm. 
>  
>  I only have one joint, 
>  Which you could call my shoulder, 
>  From which my hands point, 
>  To the values 'round the border. 
>  
>  I don't always comply, 
>  But what I tell won't end; 
>  My power source might die, 
>  Though time will still transcend.* 
>  
>  ***What am I?***

I will provide two hints in due *time*. I also accept three different answers to this (because they are really the same thing).

The title is also a clue.

---

Well, I might just provide the first hint for the fun of it, but not the second.

**Hint:**

> *The values are numeric, 
>  And placed in order, too. 
>  My invention is historic, 
>  As without it, what is due?*

Comment: @downvoter may you please explain why you downvoted? Did I do something wrong or did you not like the riddle (because this might not be your taste)? I don't care about reputation — I just want to do what is right by the community :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are obviously a

> Clock

I form ticks and crosses,
But I have not a pen.

> Tick tock

You check me during pauses, 
Every now and then.

> "Wait, what time is it?"

I have a pair of hands, 
But I have not an arm.

> The hour/minute hands.

Every day demands, 
For me to use my charm.

> Clocks often make a noise on the hour.

I only have one joint, 
Which you could call my shoulder,

> Center of the clock

From which my hands point, 
To the values 'round the border.

> The numbers around the edge of the clock.

I don't always comply, 
But what I tell won't end;

> Time goes on and on, but the clock will eventually die.

My power source might die, 
Though time will still transcend.

> As above.

I will provide two hints in due *time*. I also accept three different answers to this (because they are really the same thing).

> Notice "time" is in italics, yet another hint. "Watch" could be an alternative answer, for example. It's really just a portable clock.

A Day in a Life o' Me

> o' clock. Also **D**ay **I**n **A** **L**ife has the acronym DIAL, revealed by OP in the comments.

Comment: Wow, you are quick... Was it really this easy?? I did not even use the word "face".

Comment: @user477343 It's not really that any of the clues are that easy, but when you give so many clues to a community of people who've seen so many riddles, the riddle will surely be cracked quickly. That said, the riddle was very well constructed, especially poetically. You definitely get a +1. :)

Comment: Thank you. Also, [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Gur gvgyr nyfb unq "Qnl va n Yvsr" juvpu unf na npebalz bs QVNY.$]$ I won't bother to put up the hints, hahaha.